# How to correctly pad the output in a multi-point time series multi-label classification problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, time-series, lstm

I have a problem where the input is a collection of multivariate sequences (43 features) with variable lengths (length varies from 3 to 19-time steps ) and the output is a sequence of binary vectors (for each input time step we predict for some lab values if they are normal or out-of-range) with the same length as its input sequence. I have tried to pad the input sequences to add a mask layer, but then I have to pad the output sequences as well which will affect all my metrics. So how to probably mask the output sequences (for example if I pad output sequences with the value -1 how to tell the network to not include it in the forward propagation and loss calculation)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pad_sequences` on any sequence from tensorflow : https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/sequence/pad_sequences

```
tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(
    sequences, maxlen=None, dtype='int32', padding='pre', truncating='pre',
    value=0.0
)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I did use it on the inputs and add a masking layer to ignore the padding in the input but how can I do the same for the output?

Comment: If you want to integrate the padding in your model you should use `tf.pad`. Otherwise, you can just get the output from the model and do a post-processing padding with `pad_sequences`

Comment: Thanks again for the answer, I meant if I pad the output to be able to train the model on variable size sequences, the pad will be calculated in the metrics and the loss, so how to make the model ignore the padded output during training like we do using masking layer in the inputs?